# Positive square root of $BB^{t}$ is non-singular

Tags: matrices, functional-analysis, positive-matrices

This is the problem form Kreyszig's book (Introductory Functional Analysis) sec. 9.4 Problem  8

Let $B$ be a nonsingular $n$-rowed real square matrix and $C=BB^{t}$. Show that $C$ has a nonsingular positive square root $A$.

My problem is how to prove that $A$ is nonsingular!

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank so much

Comment: Look at the determinant?

Comment: This is very basic: every product of nonsingular matrices is nonsingular, and every product of singular matrices is singular.

Comment: How to see that $A$ is product of non-singular matrices in this case?